# How to update a new atribute in Magento with CSV file thorugh API

Tags: php, api, magento, csv, soap

I have a big numbers from Products in Magneto and i must add EAN Numbers to all the Products.
How could i update the new attribute from the CSV file through API.i want to update the EAN numbers from a ssh server through API SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full solution for you, but it is definitely a starting point for you. Good Luck

```
$productData = array(
    'additional_attributes' => array(
        'single_data' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'ean',
                'value' => 'value',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
$productId = '1000000';

$soap = new SoapConnection('1','2','3');
echo $soap->_catalogProductUpdate($productId,$productData); 


class SoapConnection
{
    protected $soap_client;
    protected $session_id;

    function __construct($soap_host, $api_user, $api_pass)
    {
        try{
            echo "Connecting to $soap_host\n";
            $this->soap_client = new SoapClient( $soap_host, array('trace' =>true,
                'connection_timeout' => 30,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'keep_alive' => false
                ));
            $this->session_id = $this->soap_client->login( $api_user, $api_pass);
            echo "Connected with session id ".$this->session_id."\n";
            return true;
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            echo "Soap Exception connecting to $soap_host: ".  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
            var_dump($this->soap_client->__getLastRequest()); var_dump($this->soap_client->__getLastResponse());
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _catalogProductUpdate($sku, $args)
    {
        try
        {
            return $this->soap_client->catalogProductUpdate($this->session_id, $sku, $args);
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            echo "Soap Exception _catalogProductUpdate: ".  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

here is how to read a csv:

```
$file = fopen("my file path .csv","r");

while($row = fgetcsv($file))
{
    $row[0];//column1
    $row[1];//column2 etc etc etc
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thanks thats work for manual updating for each ean but i tried to import it from csv but it dosent work, how can i let it read the ean and sku from the csv from fgetcsv function ? sorry but iam not profi in php ..

Comment: Added in a csv read loop for you ,just match your columns up and you should be all set